# Servlet method is not getting called?

Tags: java, servlets

I am trying to upload a file to web server and read the same. file uploading is working and the file is uploaded but when i call some methods to manipulate saved file the method is not getting called.

in the following file i call readFile method from post method.

I am using tomcat 7.0. Please save me from this. the code is :

```
package org.slingemp.fileupload;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.slingemp.bean.setNotification;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;
import org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class Fileupload
 */
@WebServlet("/Fileupload")
public class Fileupload extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public Fileupload() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
     *      response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
          System.out.println("file upload started....Antony");
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        List fileItemsList = null;
        float filesize = 0;
        String _fileLink;
        String _fileName = null;
        String _uploadDir = getServletContext().getRealPath("/accesscarddata/");
        // Change upload with your directory
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        try {
            if (ServletFileUpload.isMultipartContent(request)) {
                ServletFileUpload servletFileUpload = new ServletFileUpload(
                        new DiskFileItemFactory());
                try {
                    fileItemsList = servletFileUpload.parseRequest(request);
                } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Fileupload.class.getName()).log(
                            Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    // Change above line replace FileUploadExample with your
                    // file name
                }
                String optionalFileName = "";
                FileItem fileItem = null;

                Iterator it = fileItemsList.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    FileItem fileItemTemp = (FileItem) it.next();
                    if (fileItemTemp.isFormField()) {
                        if (fileItemTemp.getFieldName().equals("filename")) {
                            optionalFileName = fileItemTemp.getString();
                        }
                        /*
                         * If you want to pass some other data from JSP page.
                         * You can access then in this way. For each field you
                         * have do create if like below. if
                         * (fileItemTemp.getFieldName
                         * ().equals("Name of other field like:Firstname")) {
                         * String Firstname = fileItemTemp.getString(); }
                         */
                    } else {
                        fileItem = fileItemTemp;
                    }
                }
                if (fileItem != null) {
                    long size_long = fileItem.getSize();
                    filesize = size_long / 1024;
                    filesize = filesize / 1000;
                    // If you want to limit the file size. Here 30MB file size
                    // is allowed you can change it
                    //if (filesize > 30.0) {
                        // Pass error message in session.
                        //setNotification _sN = new setNotification();
                        //_sN.setError("File size can't be more than 30MB");
                        //session.setAttribute("error", _sN);
                    //} else {
                        _fileName = fileItem.getName();
                        if (fileItem.getSize() > 0) {
                            if (optionalFileName.trim().equals("")) {
                                _fileName = FilenameUtils.getName(_fileName);
                            } else {
                                _fileName = optionalFileName;
                            }
                                _fileLink = "../accesscarddata/" + _fileName;
                            try {
                                File file = new File(new File(_uploadDir + "/"),fileItem.getName());
                                fileItem.write(file);
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            setNotification _sN = new setNotification();
                            _sN.setError("File Uploaded to : " + _fileLink + "");
                            session.setAttribute("accesscardDatafileNname", _fileName);
                            session.setAttribute("error", _sN);

                        }
                    //}
                }
                //SELECT * FROM leave_application WHERE from_date >= '2004-01-01' AND to_date <'2004-01-30' and emp_id=128
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        System.out.println("before calling readFile");
        readFile(request,response);
        System.out.println("after calling readFile");

        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");

    }
    protected void readFile(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("readFile is called..");
        Map employeeMap = null;

        String fileName = "",employeeAttendanceFilePath="";
        String _uploadDir = getServletContext().getRealPath("/accesscarddata/");
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        if(session.getAttribute("accesscardDatafileNname") != null)
            fileName = (String) session.getAttribute("accesscardDatafileNname");

        employeeAttendanceFilePath = _uploadDir+fileName;
        System.out.println("File Path : "+employeeAttendanceFilePath);
        List sheetData = new ArrayList();
        FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(employeeAttendanceFilePath);
            // Create an excel workbook from the file system.
            HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(fis);
            HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);// gets the first sheet on workbook
            Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();
            while (rows.hasNext()) {
                HSSFRow row = (HSSFRow) rows.next();
                Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();
                //count=count+1;
                List data = new ArrayList();
                while (cells.hasNext()) {
                    HSSFCell cell = (HSSFCell) cells.next();
                    data.add(cell);
                }
                sheetData.add(data);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        }
        session.setAttribute("sheetData", sheetData);
        processEmployeeAttendance(request,response);
        System.out.println("employeeMap : "+employeeMap);

        if(session.getAttribute("employeeMap")!=null)
            employeeMap = (LinkedHashMap) session.getAttribute("sheetData");

        Iterator<Map.Entry> entries = employeeMap.entrySet().iterator();
        while (entries.hasNext()) {
            Map.Entry entry = entries.next();
            System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + ", Value = " + entry.getValue());
        }
    }
    protected void processEmployeeAttendance(HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        System.out.println("processEmployeeAttendance is called...");
        String tempEmpid="",strdepartment="";
        int j=1;
        List sheetData =null;
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(true);
        if(session.getAttribute("sheetData")!=null)
            sheetData = (ArrayList) session.getAttribute("sheetData");

        Map employeeMap = new LinkedHashMap();
        Map tempEmployeeMap = new LinkedHashMap();

        for (int i = 0; i < sheetData.size(); i++) {
            List list = (List) sheetData.get(i);
                HSSFCell employeeid = (HSSFCell) list.get(0);
                HSSFCell department = (HSSFCell) list.get(3);
                HSSFCell date = (HSSFCell) list.get(5);

                strdepartment = department.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
               if(!tempEmpid.equals("")){
                       if(tempEmpid.equals(employeeid.getRichStringCellValue().getString()) && !(employeeid.getRichStringCellValue().getString().equals("EmpID") || date.getRichStringCellValue().getString().equals("Date") || department.getRichStringCellValue().getString().equals("Department"))){
                           if(!(strdepartment.equals("Temporary Card") || strdepartment.equals("Contractor"))){
                               employeeMap.put(employeeid.getRichStringCellValue().getString()+"_"+j,date.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                            //      System.out.println("j value : "+j+":"+employeeid.getRichStringCellValue().getString()+"_"+j+","+date.getRichStringCellValue().getString());
                                    j++;
                            }
                       }else{
                            tempEmpid =  employeeid.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
                            j=0;
                       }
               }else{
                   tempEmpid =  employeeid.getRichStringCellValue().getString();
               }
              // System.out.println("");
        }
        session.setAttribute("employeeMap", employeeMap);
    }
}
```

Comment: What method(s) are not getting called?  What are you seeing in `catalina.out` or wherever you've configured stdout to go?

Comment: readFile is not getting called, and there is no exception thrown in tomcat console.

Comment: i tried printing something on console before and after calling readFile method but nothing is printed on the console but in the start of post method i printed something it is shown in console.

Comment: Can you add some logging code to the method and post the result?

Comment: Tomcat has several log files, so you might want to check each one since you are catching various exceptions and sending them to System.err. Ideally, you would do something useful when an exception is caught. Effectively, you are swallowing the exceptions and continuing to execute.

Comment: when i make it as war and deploy the same the file uploading is done, and tried to run in IDE the file upload itself is not done and get the following exception : java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\Fileupload\accesscarddata\C:\Users\anthony.savarimut\Desktop\Map Iterate\SampleData.xls (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to put it as a comment, but somehow I am unable to comment. 
My suggestion would be to debug the code using your IDE. Put breakpoints at relevant positions and see where its going.

Comment: when i make it as war and deploy the same the file uploading is done, and tried to run in IDE the file upload itself is not done and get the following exception : java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp1\wtpwebapps\File‌​upload\accesscarddata\C:\Users\anthony.savarimut\Desktop\Map Iterate\SampleData.xls (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)